# How to restrict that a docker container only listens connection from localhost?

Tags: docker, networking

I am running a docker container by `docker run -p 8080:8080`. Other computers can visit my server by visiting `[my ip]:8080`. However, for security reasons, I want only localhost(127.0.0.0) is able to access to my server. I do not want other people to connect to my server. How do I restrict that a docker container only listens the host `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 your_image_name
```

This will map the container's port 8080 to only listen on host's 127.0.0.1 at port 8080.