# Restrict specific docker endpoints to local subnet access only

Tags: docker, docker-network

I saw this: [How to restrict that a docker container only listens connection from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053824/how-to-restrict-that-a-docker-container-only-listens-connection-from-localhost)

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 your_image_name
```

But I want to restrict to a whole subnet. Will this work?

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.*:8080:8080 your_image_name
```

Thanks.

Comment: The bind-address part of `docker run -p` is a specific host IP address, not a subnet or CIDR block.  Firewalling and similar concerns aren't really programming-related, and depending on your needs another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.